# JavaFX Modal Dialog disappear when owner Stage is iconified/Show

Tags: modal-dialog, javafx, stage, owner

my environment: Linux Suse 12.3, JDK 1.7.0_45, JavaFX 2.2, Compiler Compliance level 1.7.

on ButtonAction a modal Dialog is opened, the Dialog Stage has an owner Stage.

now dialog is opened but if i iconified the Owner and show it again, the Dialog is not visible. (thats happen only if i set `dialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);` or `dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);`) if i remove the Modality, its working just fine. **UPDATE** (modality is not the cause too, see my second update)

**UPDATE:** *i have this Problem **ONLY** if the application is maximized. if i click the window maximize icon and then show the dialog, then iconify the Owner, now if i show the Owner application again, dialog isn't visible!*

here is the Code:

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import you.faces.resources.YF;

public class Alert {

    private String title = new String();
    private String message = new String();

    public Alert(Stage owner){
        final Stage dialog = new Stage();

        dialog.initOwner(owner); 
        dialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
            // i tried to redisplay the dialog like this, but still not working
        owner.iconifiedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(
                    final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> paramObservableValue,
                    final Boolean oldValue,
                    final Boolean newValue) {
                    if(newValue){

                    }else{  // none of these affect anything, dialog still not visible

                        dialog.setIconified(false);
                        dialog.show();
                        dialog.toFront();                       
                    }               
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getStyleClass().add("YOU-FACES-MODAL-DIALOG");
        root.getChildren().add(new Text(25, 25, "Hello World!"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,200, 100);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(YF.INSTANCE.getFile("clientUI.css"));
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        dialog.setScene(scene);
        //relativeToOwner(dialog,owner);
        dialog.show();
    }

    private void relativeToOwner(Stage stage, Stage owner) {
        stage.setX(owner.getX() + owner.getWidth() / 2 - stage.getWidth() / 2);
        stage.setY(owner.getY() + owner.getHeight() / 2 - stage.getHeight() / 2);

    }
}
```

any idea how to deal with this Problem?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you misinterpreted due to the dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT). Remove this line and try again.

Comment: @Uluk Biy: i tried your tip. its not the cause of this Problem. as i said, if i remove the Modality it works fine. but i need it modal.

Comment: But I said about the stage's style and not its modality.

Comment: yes and i said i tried your tip, i removed the style as you said. but its not the solution.

Comment: This maybe caused by your environment. Tested your code and scenario on Win7 with JavaFX 2.2.21, and working as expected. No disappearing. And of course tried without loading "clientUI.css".

Comment: thank you Uluk Biy, i think so too. FX su..., soo many bugs on Linux.